# Get-NetAdapter from Get-VMSwitch

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I would like to retreive network adapters used by Hyper-V Virtual Switch through Powershell.

Current investigations:

```
Get-VMSwitch | Select-Object NetAdapterInterfaceGuid
{9894bc20-46fe-4b77-8ba8-6fd49d475dbe}
```

```
Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object InterfaceGuid
{AFA2B52A-E930-414B-885C-F89BC03D8290}
{9894BC20-46FE-4B77-8BA8-6FD49D475DBE}
{5747ABCD-DA1E-4604-BC85-3C944D5773FB}
{21A87E0B-00D7-461B-8154-A4D1BD23C49C}
{188F4D83-9D64-4287-8461-695E17102BF4}
```

There is a UUID match but the format is not the same.

When I try to provide the vSwitch NetAdapter UUID to the Get-NetAdapter command, there is a data format exception

```
Get-VMSwitch | ForEach-Object {$_ | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru -Name networkInterfaces -Value @(Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex $_.NetAdapterInterfaceGuid)} | select-object Id,Name,networkInterfaces
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Cannot convert the
"9894bc20-46fe-4b77-8ba8-6fd49d475dbe" value of type "System.Guid" to type "System.UInt32".
```

Does there is a way to convert System.Guid to System.UInt32 or another way to retreive Net-Adapters from Hyper-V vSwitch?

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Guid[]] $occupiedNetAdaterGuids = Get-VMSwitch | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetAdapterInterfaceGuid
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$occupiedNetAdaterGuids -contains $_.InterfaceGuid}
```

The first line takes all VM switches, extracts `GUID` of the network adapter to which is the VM switch bind to and stores these network adapter `GUID`s into an array.

The second line takes all network adapters and pipes them into a filter which removes the adapters with no VM switch bound to them.

#### Notes

In PowerShell, it is very important to ensure type safety, especially with arrays. PowerShell is not a strongly typed language. The `[System.Guid[]]` ensures that the output from `Get-VMSwitch` is converted into array event when one GUID is returned.

The `ExpandProperty` extracts the value of the property, so no `PSCustomObject` is returned, only the value itself.

The change of the condition from `-contains` to `-notcontains` inverse the result. It will return the adapters not used by Hyper-V VM switches.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: @sta The answer was updated. BTW: You have a type in your profile. The quote is from R. Reagan, not ReagOn. 